# adobe acrobat pro xi save as PDFs optimized using command line?

Tags: command-line, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a directory I would like to reduce in size that contains about 4,570 files.

I have Adobe Acrobat Pro and the Save As PDF optimized seems like it's doing a good job but obviously I can't do them all one by one.

I know enough C# to scan the directory and get a list then pipe it into a commandeer but I'm not sure where to find the proper commands, e.g. `adobe.exe /saveasoptomized C:/filename` or something along those lines.

Comment: http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Optimize+PDF+File+Size

Comment: Here's how to do it with the Action Wizard: https://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-I-batch-optimize-PDF-folders-AcrobatX-q19602.aspx

Comment: action wizard seems to be working fine. post it as an answer and ill mark it